# How to set up autoprefixer.browsers value using docpad.coffee config?

Tags: coffeescript, stylus, docpad, autoprefixer

*(What a mess to find all the below setup infos already :-/ )*

I could get autoprefixer to run with docpad, but I (guess I) did not succeed in setting the `browsers` value...

## my environment:

- **docpad 6.69.1**
- IE 11, FF 31.0 + Firebug

What I tried so far (docpad install with **plugins: jade, less, livereload, marked**):

## simple install worked (default `browsers` setup):

1. **`docpad install autoprefix`**

I got some `style.css.less` file with some imports and especially some **`background: radial-gradient(...) ; background: linear-gradient(...)`** rules.

2. I renamed my **`style.css.less` to `style.css.autoprefix.css.less`** (`style.css.autoprefix.less` did not work)

Till here it worked only with warning(s) about that the `less->css` or `css->autoprefix` conversions did not do anything which should be ok.

**autoprefixer added some `-webkit...` versions of my `...gradient...` rules above.**

## not possible to set `browsers` without docpad stylus plugin?

... it seemed to me ... so I continued like this:

3. **`docpad install stylus`**
4. **added the autoprefixer stylus setup to my `docpad.coffee` setup file:**

   ```
   docpadConfig = {

     #...

     plugins:
       stylus:
         stylusLibraries:
           'autoprefixer-stylus': true
         options:
           use: [
             #() -> require('autoprefixer-stylus')('ie 6')
             () -> require('autoprefixer-stylus')('ff > 3')
             #() -> require('autoprefixer-stylus')('last 2 versions')
           ]
   }

   # Export our DocPad Configuration
   module.exports = docpadConfig
   ```

The effect is, that now my `style.css` is obviously autoprefixed again, but switching between the options above does not have an effect.

## How to make `browsers` settings work from here?

All the setup info to here I collected from different sources so I likely missed something. Maybe it is already possible to configure the `browsers` settings without the *stylus* plugin?

Here the sources that helped me more or less to get to this point:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/docpad-plugin-autoprefix
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/docpad-plugin-stylus
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-stylus
- http://blog.sapegin.me/all/css-workflow
- https://github.com/kizu/docpad-test/blob/master/docpad.coffee

## My main test case

Adding the additional `-moz-radial-gradient...`/`-moz-linear-gradient...` rules in my css manually shows me the proper gradients. Removing them doesn't show any gradient (not even from the standard syntax and independent of using the autoprefixer ... this may be an unrelated/left problem, because I would expect the much more complex *style.css* to change on the above `browsers` options changes at least gradually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works - the **problem layed somewhere else!**

**Thus the question already contains the answer how to set it up** ...

The following ***gradient*-related issue** made me check for my **gradient-syntax**:

https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/91

And following the specs: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

more thoroughly and since changing

```
background: linear-gradient( top,         red,  yellow);
background: radial-gradient( top right,   red,  yellow);
```

to

```
background: linear-gradient( to bottom left,                        red,  yellow )
background: radial-gradient( ellipse farthest-corner at top right,  red,  yellow )
```

it works like a charm :-)